# Get real ip from listener with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, icecast, shoutcast, internet-radio

I try to make proxy icecast/shoutcast radio with nginx and get real ip from listener.

If i put localhost ip

```
location /exampleradio/ {
    proxy_buffering           off;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
    proxy_intercept_errors    on;
    proxy_next_upstream       error timeout invalid_header;
    proxy_redirect            off;
    proxy_connect_timeout     60;
    proxy_send_timeout        21600;
    proxy_read_timeout        21600;

    proxy_set_header Host 127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

the listener ip it shows correctly,

When i put another radio from another server example:

```
location /exampleradio1/ {
    proxy_buffering           off;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
    proxy_intercept_errors    on;
    proxy_next_upstream       error timeout invalid_header;
    proxy_redirect            off;
    proxy_connect_timeout     60;
    proxy_send_timeout        21600;
    proxy_read_timeout        21600;

    proxy_set_header Host cast.example.com:8000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://cast.example.com:8000;
}
```

the listener ip on another server it shows the **server ip** and no **listener ip**.
How can i solve this and get listener ip and no server ip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only server that supports "X-Forwarded-For" header is Icecast-kh.

Switch to Icecast-kh, leave your Nginx config as is and don't forget to add

`<x-forwarded-for>_PROXY IP HERE_</x-forwarded-for>`

to your Icecast-kh config.

Comment: Better yet, just ditch Nginx from out in front in the first place.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the same problem. For my part, I go through [Traefik](https://containo.us/traefik/), it's more or less the same as Nginx, which I tested before. The `<x-forwarded-for>` configuration doesn't exist in the base file `icecast.xml` of Icecast-KH package. Where did you find this information?

Comment: THIS is the solution I searched since 10 days ! Congratulations and thousand of thanks ! It works very well [issues/195](https://github.com/karlheyes/icecast-kh/issues/195#issuecomment-348639685)