# Icecast behind Apache proxy setup - How to preserve the original listener IP

Tags: apache, proxy, ip, icecast, preserve

I have an icacast-kh server running on port 8000 behind apache proxy.
On Icecast admin page in listeners stats, I can't see the original IP listener.
I have followed a few tutorials on how to preserve the original IP when using Apache, but for some unknown reason, it does not work with Icecast. I need this to be working with Apache and not with nginx (I found a solution for this problem but it uses nginx).

Here are more details about my current setup:

- icecast-2.4.0-kh15
- ubuntu 20.04
- Apache/2.4.41

Here is the host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName live.domain.com
     ServerAdmin info@domain.com

     RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
     RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.0/8

     ProxyPreserveHost On

     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is part of the icecast config:

```
<hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
    </listen-socket>
    ...
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022812/get-real-ip-from-listener-with-nginx-proxy/61026627#61026627

Comment: @AlexParamonov - Thank you! I don't know how I missed this StackOverflow question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexParamonov i have manage to fix this.

In icecast XML config add to the  node:

```
<paths>
     <x-forwarded-for>127.0.0.1</x-forwarded-for>
     ...
</paths>
```