# Display original source IP address in Icecast server logs

Tags: icecast

I have an issue whereby the the IP addresses of the connected listeners are being replaced with the actual servers IP address. I suspect that this is happening due to using the HTTPS proxy. I am seeing this in the /admin/listclients.xsl?mount=/stream page of the Icecast server.

Is there a way to modify the Icecast server to take the original source IP address (in square brackets represented as yyy) and have it displayed in the IP field as shown in the logs below.

In the example below xxx IP addresses are the actual servers IP addresses and yyy are the actual genuine, original listener IP addresses.

Is there somewhere in a config file for the Icecast server I can change this behaviour?

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 142592  Liquidsoap/1.2.1+scm (Unix; OCaml 4.01.0)   [ip:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]    Kick
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 142532  WinampMPEG/5.50                             [ip:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]    Kick
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 128203  GStreamer souphttpsrc 1.20.3 libsoup/2.74.2 [ip:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]    Kick
```

I have full access to the server.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="IP" />
        <xsl:if test="username">
            (<xsl:value-of select="username" />)
        </xsl:if>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Connected" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="UserAgent" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="killclient.xsl?mount={$themount}&amp;id={ID}">Kick</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Regular Icecast doesn't support this, but the KH version supports `X-Forwarded-For`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get real ip from listener with nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022812/get-real-ip-from-listener-with-nginx-proxy)

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your reply, appreciated. I'm not keen to switch to KH at the moment. As the original IP address is actually already in the log, could I not somehow manipulate how the file is being read to make the correct IP address appear in that field? See my edit above. The correct IP address exists in the UserAgent field. Thanks.